# Wait time for response when receiving Twilio SMS messages

Tags: sms, twilio

When my app receives a Twilio SMS message, how long does Twilio wait for a response from my app?  What happens if that time has been exceeded (ie. does Twilio send back an error code, log an error in your Twilio account, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [11200 error](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200) is an indicator of a connection failure between Twilio and your service. When Twilio requests a page from your server, we wait a maximum of 15 seconds for a response. A connection failure will occur if no response is returned in that time.

Comment: Great.  Thanks for the info Megan.

Comment: Also, I posted this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36927205/twilio-sms-multi-part-messages     Do you know the answer to it too?  Thanks