# Twilio SMS multi part messages

Tags: sms, twilio

When receiving MMS messages through Twilio, some phones/service providers may split multiple attachments up into multiple, separate text messages even though the originator of the text message attached them into the same text message.

When receiving the messages, is there some way (hopefully a key of some kind) that my app can use to determine that multiple messages coming in should be grouped together and consider part of the same text message?

Comment: I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) with examples of messages where this has happened. Twilio should be able to put messages back together, like you're after, but if it isn't happening we should look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio supports [inbound concatenated messages](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/does-twilio-support-concatenated-sms-messages-or-messages-over-160-characters) up to 1,600 characters. Inbound messages over 160 characters will also be received on your Twilio phone number as one single message.

While this is dependent upon carrier like you said, you can always check a messages [instance resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#instance), where messages are easily identified by their `Sid`.

And as Phil mentioned, if you are experiencing unexpected behavior send examples of those messages to [Twilio Support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) for further examination.