# Change Twilio SMS Inbound Request Timeout

Tags: twilio, aws-lambda

[I saw that Twilio has a default 15 second timeout for SMS inbound requests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36948488/9636). I'm using a Java-based AWS Lambda behind API Gateway for my SMS inbound requests, and it takes a few seconds to spin up a java-based lambda function if it's been dormant for a while. Is it possible to increase my timeout in Twilio?

Answer (score 1):

I've been having issues with Twilio not being able to connect to our server within the 15 second timeout and their support just plainly refuses to increase the timeout. So no, you can't increase it.

You can provide a fallback URL but it is not helping things at all for us.

Something is not right with their setup, they should have built in retries like other service providers.